# How to Copy children using XSL

Tags: xml, xslt

How do I copy children using XSL?

Source:

```
<body>
   <keyword><i color="blue">super</i>man</keyword>
   <keyword><i color="blue">super</i>man</keyword>
   <keyword><i color="blue">super</i>woman</keyword>
</body>
```

I am using the following

```
  <xsl:template match="keyword" >
    <keyword>
      <xsl:attribute name="type">Key Words Head First</xsl:attribute>

      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
    </keyword>

  </xsl:template>
```

When using the above code I am getting double nested `<keyword>` tags.

Thanks.

Comment: What does the source xml look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to output a `keyword` explicitly *and* copy the existing `keyword` using `xsl:copy`. As an alternative to *@DevNull*'s answer:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="keyword">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:attribute name="type">Key Words Head First</xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

...produces the following, when applied to your input:

```
<body>
    <keyword type="Key Words Head First"><i color="blue">super</i>man</keyword>
    <keyword type="Key Words Head First"><i color="blue">super</i>man</keyword>
    <keyword type="Key Words Head First"><i color="blue">super</i>woman</keyword>
</body>
```

**From the comments:**

> ...what if the attribute needs to be overridden. Like suppose
>   'keyword' already has a 'type' attribute.

In that case, don't copy the existing `type` attribute:

```
<xsl:template match="keyword">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:attribute name="type">Key Words Head First</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*[not(name()='type')]|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thanks. I don't show this in the example, but what if the attribute needs to be overridden. Like suppose 'keyword' already has a 'type' attribute. I tested your code and it does not overwrite it.

Comment: +1 for doing it like I would do it. This is more helpful to the OP than my answer.

Comment: @joe - see my updated answer for ignoring existing `@type`. You could also use the same predicate in @lwburk's answer.

Answer (score 3):

`xsl:copy` is copying the context item, which in this case is `keyword`. Basically you're wrapping the existing `keyword` with a new one.

Try removing the `xsl:copy`:

```
  <xsl:template match="keyword" >
    <keyword type="Key Words Head First">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*[name() != 'type']"/>
    </keyword>    
  </xsl:template>
```

Note: Your final output will depend on whether you have other templates to handle the children of `keyword` (like an identity transform).

You can find more information on copying and the identity transform here: http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#copying

Comment: +1 - Perfectly good answer. Arguably better, since it's one line fewer. I only provided mine to show that it can be done both ways.